# charset for different foreign languages

Tags: php, character-encoding

My website is in portuguese, english and russian. Today I update the php version to 5.4, and all my languages are with strange charaters and the russian is really bad.. 
I have utf8 at all my data base but the strange charaters continues.
example:
PortuguÃªs = Português

How can I set it in order to fit all this different languages ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have different links to your website. For example: website.com/ru or website.com/en. It can get messy, because this uses many copies of the same code. For a page to have special characters you have to do 3 things:

- Set the *.php file to UTF-8 format (http://tinypic.com/r/ua1vl/8)
- Set the meta tag ()
- Set the database character set to UTF-8

Comment: I already have the database charater set to utf8, and yes I have different links like you said it. I will try the rest thank you very much